# Rails 4 + Friendly_id: URL not showing slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, slug, friendly-id

I am using `Friendly_ID` for slugs on my site and it is working...sort of.  I can access the routes correctly, but when I follow a link to the page, it still shows the id.  For example, I have a link that shows the following:

```
<%= link_to "X", location_path(@location, :id => "1")
```

which displayed the url as `localhost:3000/locations/1` so I changed the link to:

```
<%= link_to "X", location_path(@location, :id => "X")
```

which displays properly (`localhost:3000/locations/X`) but when you look at the `href` of the link in after you navigate to its page, it is displayed as `<a ... href="/locations/X.X">...</a>`.

**Why is the link displaying `X.X` and not simple `X`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `id` to the `location_path`. It will be picked up from `@location`. Drop `id` from `location_path` and it should fix the problem.

Comment: I get the following error when I do that: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`.  I have this link on the home page, with multiple locations so `@location` doesn't know which `location to link to

Comment: How are you setting the `@location` value. If you add your controller code, it will help further review.

Comment: I ended up correcting this in the controller by declaring a different variable for each location, and calling that in the path